# Run crontab every 15 minutes + at specific time in one line?

Tags: cron

In short words I need to do that in one line:

```
0,15,30,45  * * * * my_command
50,55      23 * * * my_command
```

I want to run some command every 15 minutes + two extra times before midnight.
Is it possible to do this in one crontab's line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cron is at heart a very simple scheduler.

What you are currently doing, writing two different schedules that combined achieve a much more complex schedule than what native cron syntax would support is usually the best solution.

That is an intuitive solution that other admins can also easily read and understand.

An other solution is to simply schedule your job to run much more frequently.

You should then build additional logic into your job (or a shell script wrapper around the actual job) that checks if the conditions are right for the job to be run (and those condition can then be much more complex that just a check of the time) and when they are not, exit gracefully.

That approach, a check if the conditions are suitable at the start of the job before starting the actual work and exiting gracefully when not, can be, when done correctly,  a very powerful solution that solves a whole range potential potential problems that CRON normally wouldn't be able to address.
(For instance a common check in high frequency batch jobs is to prevent multiple scheduled batches from running concurrently when suddenly one batch takes much longer to process than expected and doesn't complete before cron has scheduled a next iteration.)

In pseudo code:

a cron job:

```
 * * * * * *  /path/to/wrapper_for_my_job
```

and

```
 #!/bin/your-favourite-scripting-language
 # wrapper_for_my_job: only execute my_job when the time is right


 if current_time == [0,15,30,45 minutes past the hour]
    then 
        my_job
 else if current_time == [23:50 ETC OR 23:55 UTC]
     then 
         my_job
 else
      exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Command:
*/15 * * * * /path/to/command
If it's for specific user then you can run it as */15 * * * * USER /path/to/command

Answer (score 0):

You could run the cron every 0,15,30,45,50,55 and add a check of the time at the beginning of the cron.

Orherwise no, I don't think it's possible given there's little incentive to support a convoluted syntax that would permit it better than adding a second line.

Comment: could You please provide mora information about the extra checks? I can run command every 5 minutes, but in the command check, but I'm not sure if You mean that solution?